# How to make a Blazor WebAssembly app listen for http requests?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Is it possible to have an http server running in a Blazor WebAssembly App (on the client)? The scenario would be the following:

- I have a client app (Blazor WebAssembly) running on a device.
- Some other devices would have to do GET/POST requests to this client app.

It does not need to be super complicated, a simple text response from the WASM app would do just fine. Is it possible to do something like this or should I try to find another approach?

Comment: Good question... What have you tried to do? I would try starting a basic `TcpListener` and see if you can get a connection to it.

Comment: Having a TcpListener or an HttpListener in a method in a razor view is not working. 
"Unhandled exception rendering component: Operation is not supported on this platform.". Yet, maybe what I am doing is wrong and the listener should be placed somewhere else.

Comment: It's saying it's not supported on the platform, then they probably haven't ported any socket routines (Socket, TcpListener, etc) to Blazor WASM yet. And probably won't as it's not a typical task (probably for security reasons). This would be a great question to post on Blazor's GitHub repo.

Comment: @Andy - they haven't ported those because they wouldn't run (on Wasm).